# HP Pavilion 762n power supply model information

Tags: power-supply, hp-pavilion

The power supply on my ancient Hp Pavilion 762n desktop has finally appeared to have kicked the bucket. The green light on the back of the machine lights up, but when I push the power button on the front (which sticks) nothing happens (could be the case?)

I googled my fingers off and couldn't find any information on the exact power supply to use. Anyone have a manual handy perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful with HP machines (and some Dell's as I've learned to my chagrin) and power supplies.  HP has in the past (and maybe still does) used power supply connectors that are very nonstandard.  On the bright side they use a different **size**, so any question of whether they put the pins in the right place is moot, so you need not worry about accidentally burning out the motherboard.

The problem is that a standard ATX power supply will not necessarily work in an HP machine.  You should make sure that the motherboard connector fits before purchasing a given power supply.  I recommend measuring the motherboard connector with a ruler and taking that measurement and ruler to the computer shop.  If is the same, you win!.  Otherwise you'll have to get one from HP if you can, or (possibly) get an adapter.  Those can be hard to find though.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need a specific model power supply.  Any ATX compatible power supply will do, provided it has sufficient wattage.  Any decent power supply should do the trick.